# Mount my windows disk partition on a Linux system

Tags: linux, mount, administration

The question is whether and how to mount a Win10 partition over the network, so I can access that partition from my Linux machine.

My company uses Linux Redhat 7. The company admin allocated me a space which is not enough. My laptop runs windows 10. I was wondering, can I mount one of my laptop disk partition to my Linux account to extend my limited Linux space. If so, how to do it?
BTW, I can see and access my Linux space the company admin created for me, from my laptop through a path like : \servermango\users\myaccount.

Comment: So basically what you're asking is whether and how to mount a Win10 partition over the network, such that you can access that partition from your Linux machine, is that correct?

Comment: @polemon That is a correct rephrasing.

Comment: My first guess is to share the disk or a useful directory of it in Windows and mount it as Samba Filesystem in Linux.

Comment: @mozartsg then please edit your question, such that the nature of the problem is more evident. If your question is easier to understand (and to the point) at first glance, your chances of getting a swift answer will increase, etc.